# Smartgwt addMember changes top of parent

Tags: layout, location, smartgwt

I have several nested layouts (VLayouts and HLayouts), which are included inside a tab pane. In one of these layouts (VLayout), there is severall elements which are added or removed dynamically depending on a window of selection. The first time the user makes a selection, the pane moves up several pixels (and you will not see the upper part of the pane). The rest of times, the pain remains in the wrong place.

In summary, the first adding affects to the top of the pane, and the rest of adding/removing doesn't affect to it.

This only happens on Chrome. However, Firefox and IE work ok.

My code of adding is:

```
int total = itemsPanel.getMembers().length - 1;
while (total >=0) {
    itemsPanel.removeMember(itemsPanel.getMember(total));
    total--;
}


Record[] records = selectorWindow.getSelectedRows();
if (records != null) {
    for (Record record : records) {
        String name = record.getAttribute("keyRecord");
        HLayout item = items.get(name);
        itemsPanel.addMember(row);
    }
}
if (itemsPanel != null) {
    int r = 80;
    if (Utils.isReducedHeight()) {
        r = 120;
    }

    int visibleHeight = getVisibleHeight() - StyleUtils.HEADER_HEIGHT - r;
    itemsPanel.setHeight(Math.max(1, Math.min(itemsPanel.getMembers().length * Utils.getRowHeight(), visibleHeight)));
    int h = Math.min(itemsPanel.getHeight() + 10, visibleHeight);
    containerItemsPanel.setHeight(h);
}
```

I'm using gwt 2.5.1 and smartgwt 3.0. Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Whenever you're facing an issue related to design, it's always better to attach snapshots describing the same for easy understanding.

Comment: Minor detail, but there is no GWT 2.5.1. Maybe you mean 2.5.0 RC1. Also your code snippet has many methods whose side effects aren't shown to us. These could be the reason for the problems you experience. Try to provide a self contained example we can test, thus we can help you to find a solution.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer. The version I have installed in eclipse is google suit plugin 2.5.1.v201201120043-rel-r37. I supossed that it was the same than gwt 2.5.1, sorry.